# casting variables and select username in oracle 12c

Tags: oracle

What type of variables should `select user from dual` return?

If is not `varchar`, how can I cast to `varchar(30)` or `varchar2(30)`?

Does a method exist which returns the current user name better than it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to:

```
select dump(user) from dual;
```

it is type 1, [which is `varchar2`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6). (Or `nvarchar2`, based just on that number.) The length - the number of bytes - varies, of course, as it's *var*char.

The documentation [for the `user` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/USER.html) also says:

> This function returns a VARCHAR2 value.

You can cast the user to `varchar2(30)`:

```
select cast(user as varchar2(30)) from dual;
```

but according to dump it's exactly the same afterwards. You'd only see a difference if the username was longer than 30 characters to start with; then it would be truncated. However, the docs also say:

> Oracle Database compares values of this function with blank-padded comparison semantics.

Which means that if my username is, say, `STACKOVERFLOW` then both of these return data:

```
select * from dual where user = 'STACKOVERFLOW';
select * from dual where user = 'STACKOVERFLOW          ';
```

The blank-padded comparison means that it's padding the result of `user` to the length of the literal it's being compared with.

Once you cast the result that is no longer true as it reverts to nonpadded comparison:

```
select * from dual where cast(user as varchar2(30)) = 'STACKOVERFLOW';
```

gets a row back but this does not:

```
select * from dual where cast(user as varchar2(30)) = 'STACKOVERFLOW     ';
```

---

An alternative is to use [`sys_context()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SYS_CONTEXT.html):

```
select sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') from dual;
```

which also returns `varchar2`, and again that be cast to little effect; and this uses nonpadded comparison, so again

```
select * from dual where sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') = 'STACKOVERFLOW'
```

finds data but this does not:

```
select * from dual where sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') = 'STACKOVERFLOW     '
```

... with or without explicit casting.